# C# function call doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code, but the call of my function `Insert()` doesn't work.

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        Insert();
    }
}

public IEnumerator Insert() {

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    //add some fields

    WWW request = new WWW(url, form);
    yield return request;

    string result = request.text;

    if (result == "error") {
        yield return null;
    }
    print(result);
}
```

I work with Unity, and if I name the `Insert()` function `Start()` (to be called directly on start), the function works well, there is no problem.

Do you know what is the problem and how to solve it ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Start function is a special function like Update which is called through reflection through unity it looks like you've created a co-routine which should be called  StartCorutine(Insert()),

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in `Update`, what happens when you run it?

Comment: Which means you have to call that method somewhere, because `Insert`is *no such* special name and thus isn´t handled by unity.

Comment: @sab669 I told him how to call it StartCorutine(Insert())

Comment: @sab669 this is exatly that. The code works fine in the start function, but not when i call it in the update function

Comment: pretty sure this line will cause an endless loop on error, you should be calling yield break
if (result == "error") {
        yield return null;
}

Comment: @johnny5 what is a co-routine ? Do I need to replace the call `Insert();` by `StartCoroutine(Insert());` ?

Comment: Have you ever tried reading [Unity's documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com)? They have something called [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

Comment: @LucasPierrat Google it. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Comment: Native unity does not support threads, so your code is call in a loop, your Insert function is IEnumerator which needs to be called via a co-routine si yes replace the insert call with start coroutine

Comment: johnny said the answer like 10 comments ago. The OP doesn't understand coroutines, which is the problem

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't understand, it is my first time with Unity and C#

Comment: @johnny5 with your solution I have the following problem : " WWW is not ready downloading yet"

Comment: @LucasPierrat is that an error message or is that what prints out.  Where are you trying to post to? Are you sure you have a server listening

Comment: Yes, my server was down I don't know why... Now the problem is solved. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using StartCoroutine which is needed to for IEnumerators.

Try this instead:

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        StartCoroutine(Insert());
    }
}
```

Also, this answer was informed to you in the comments a couple times, but I'm posting the answer as to solve the issue and make it easier for other people running into this problem to find the answer quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
```

instead of `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))`

Comment: I don't think it is the solution because the if works correctly. It is just the call of the function that doesn't work

Comment: `Input.GetKeyDown` has overloads for both a `String` and.. I assume `KeyCode` is probably an enum. No harm in trying, but I'd be thoroughly surprised if this made a difference. As the others said, it seems to be an issue with how he's calling `Insert` from `Update`, since it's going to get called multiple times (presumably) whereas when being called from `Start`, it's only going to run exactly once.